# C# override Dictionary ContainsKey

Tags: c#, dictionary, overriding

I just can't find any proper piece of code to do what i need.

Im using `Dict.ContainsKey` but due to the fact im always creating the Key i need to look for, i always get false for the ContainsKey (because hashKey is different and im creating the key i want to check all the time).

can someone please advise how to override Contains key or how to handle keys comparing in this situation ?
My dictionary Looks like 
`Dictionary<someObj, int>`

```
public class someObj
{
    public int someobjParam {get;set;}
    public int someobjParamTwo {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to override `ContainsKey`, but rather instruct the dictionary when it should consider that two keys are equal.

One way to do that is by implementing [`IEquatable<someObj>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your key class. Do this if the concept of equality is global across your app:

```
public class someObj : IEquatable<someObj>
{
    public int someobjParam {get;set;}
    public int someobjParamTwo {get;set;}

    // override GetHashCode() and Equals(); for an example
    // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
}
```

Another one is by implementing an `IEqualityComparer<someObj>` and passing it to the dictionary's constructor.

Comment: @Sameer: It's not really different, although I 'm working on it. Jon just hit Enter first.

Comment: It's actually different. This answer do same java syntax mixed up with C#, but it also solves the same problem a different way (by implementing an interface which is used by the ContainsKey method). Edit: and now Jon Skeet's answer also has the IEquatable suggestion as well

Comment: @Jon: You've used "implements" instead of ":".

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to override `ContainsKey` - you need to *either* override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `someObj` (which should be renamed to conform to .NET naming conventions, btw) *or* you need to pass an [`IEqualityComparer<someObj>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the [`Dictionary<,>` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Either way, that code is used to compare keys (and obtain hash codes from them).

Basically you need to make `Equals` determine equality, and make `GetHashCode` return the same code for equal objects and ideally different codes for different objects - see [Eric Lippert's article on `GetHashCode`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) for more details.

Also, you should consider making `someObj` immutable: mutable dictionary keys are generally a bad idea, as if you modify the key in a hashcode-sensitive way after using it as a key within the dictionary, you won't be able to find it again. If the point of your custom type really is to be a key, then just make it immutable.

For simplicity, you should also consider making `someObj` implement [`IEquatable<someObj>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and also think about whether it would be appropriate to be a struct instead of a class. If you implement `IEquatable<someObj>` you should *also* override `object.Equals` in a consistent way. Usually the `object.Equals` implementation will just call the most strongly-typed `IEquatable<T>.Equals` implementation.

Comment: can you give me a code sample please? i know that is the problem as i mentioned it in my question.

Comment: @OriRefael: Well which bit of my answer would stump you? Have you *tried* overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` appropriately in `someObj`? It's best if you try it for yourself rather than just getting other people to write code for you. Also, your question really isn't clear (in my view) which doesn't help us help you...

Comment: you were right if i wasn't under stress now and needed it fast to solve something. it would be nice if you try only to help and thats it. thx for the explaination though.

Comment: @OriRefael: I *am* trying to help - I'm trying to help you become a better developer, by learning to put advice into practice yourself, and by giving you advice about other things to think about (immutability etc).

Comment: Asking someone else to write code isn't very scalable.  The other way to be lazy (one of the three virtues) is to use a Visual Studio extension to automatically generate this code.  For example, R# has a function, "Generate -> Equality Members" to do this stuff automatically.

Comment: @Brian: In this case the accepted answer doesn't even actually *have* the code - it has a couple of comments and `: IEquatable<someObj>`, but it's otherwise as per the question. Odd.